# Extract contents from a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I have my clients data stored in a nested list in R, in the same way than this one:

```
myinventedlist <- list("LOLETE" = list("Name" = "LOLETE",
                                "location" = "Huelva",
                                "Employees" = "22",
                                "SM" = "eJeK1",
                                "Groups" = list("ABUELOs" = list("PICHI" = list("fab_name" = "Pichi (ES)", "fab_id" = "2323423ES", "fab_tarif" = "6A"),
                                                                 "PACHA" = list("fab_name" = "Pacha (AG)", "fab_id" = "1231212AG", "fab_tarif" = "6A"),
                                                                 "POCHO" = list("fab_name" = "Pocho (ED)", "fab_id" = "2132192ED", "fab_tarif" = "6A")),
                                             "PRIMOts" = list("MONGO" = list("fab_name" = "MONGO (LB)", "fab_id" = "21332238LB", "fab_tarif" = "6A"),
                                                              "MINGO" = list("fab_name" = "MINGO (NT)", "fab_id" = "22231220NT", "fab_tarif" = "6B"),
                                                              "MUNGO" = list("fab_name" = "MUNGO (CQ)", "fab_id" = "23215001CQ", "fab_tarif" = "6B")))),
                       "GUPERA" =  list("Name" = "GUPERA",
                                          "location" = "Madrid",
                                          "Employees" = "113",
                                          "SM" = "1xa3P",
                                          "Groups" = list("ABUELOs" = list("YYTER" = list("fab_name" = "YYTER (MM)", "fab_id" = "2323423MM", "fab_tarif" = "6A"),
                                                                           "LOLE" = list("fab_name" = "LOLE (NN)", "fab_id" = "1231212NN", "fab_tarif" = "6A"),
                                                                           "PEEE" = list("fab_name" = "PEE (EE)", "fab_id" = "2132192EE", "fab_tarif" = "6A")))))
```

I would like extract a vector with all "fab_id" from a cliente given its name (In this case "LOLETE" or "GUPERA").

I can access the desired content, that is, all "fab_id" from a certain Client, but it is a horrible way to do so:

```
cliente <- "LOLETE"
firstindex <- which(names(myinventedlist) == eval(cliente))
secondindex <- which(names(myinventedlist[[firstindex]]) == "Groups")
sapply(myinventedlist[[firstindex]][[secondindex]][[1]], "[[", "fab_id")
sapply(myinventedlist[[firstindex]][[secondindex]][[2]], "[[", "fab_id")
```

Which gives:

```
      PICHI       PACHA       POCHO 
"2323423ES" "1231212AG" "2132192ED" 

       MONGO        MINGO        MUNGO 
"21332238LB" "22231220NT" "23215001CQ
```

I would like that given the client I could recover all the "fab_id" disregarding the "Group" they belong to. The client is passed as a String.

In another words, I would like to be able to obtain all the elements values that are labelled under certain a title (like "fab_name") within a list, altough they might be included in nested lists (like "Groups").

I would like to take adventage and ask if in this kind of list for storing data that will be used recursevely in a project it is good to name the clients as "CLIENT01" and then add the field "clien_name" within the list or if it is ok to name the list directly with the name of the client. What is the typical way to go?

Any good link to work with lists in R in this sense is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unlist`, then subset by names `grepl`:

```
res <- unlist(myinventedlist[[ cliente ]])
res[ grepl("fab_id", names(res)) ]
# Groups.ABUELOs.PICHI.fab_id Groups.ABUELOs.PACHA.fab_id Groups.ABUELOs.POCHO.fab_id Groups.PRIMOts.MONGO.fab_id 
# "2323423ES"                 "1231212AG"                 "2132192ED"                "21332238LB" 
# Groups.PRIMOts.MINGO.fab_id Groups.PRIMOts.MUNGO.fab_id 
# "22231220NT"                "23215001CQ"
```